# Wrapping C++ with Go build

Tags: c++, go, swig

I am trying to wrap C++ code ([LabStreamingLayer](https://github.com/sccn/labstreaminglayer/)) in Go.

**Update**: @dragonx explained how to use `go build` without `swig`. But I am still running into a linker issue. The build depends on `LSL/liblsl/bin/liblsl.dylib`. How do I tell `go build` to use that file? I tried `go build -ldflags "-L ../liblsl/bin -l lsl" app.go` with no success.

The [Go documentation](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Calling_between_Go_and_C) says that `go build` will invoke Swig with the `c++` option for files with the `.swigcxx` extension, but `go build` complains that there are no buildable Go source files in the directory.

- Platform: Darwin
- Go version: 1.8
- Swig version:  3.0.12
- clang version: 8.0.0

Here are the steps I took to arrive at that error:

1. Clone the labstreaminglayer repo.
2. Rename the file [`liblsl_cpp.i`](https://github.com/sccn/labstreaminglayer/blob/master/LSL/liblsl-Generic/liblsl_cpp.i) to `liblsl.swigcxx` (I thought this would tell `go build` that the file should be used with swig).
3. `cd` into `LSL/liblsl-Generic` and run `go build`. Go complains that there are no buildable Go source files in this directory.

After that failed, I tried using Swig. I ran `swig -c++ -go -cgo -intgosize 64 liblsl_cpp.i`, which created a `.go` file. I then ran `go build` in that directory, but it raised the error:

```
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1
```

I am not familiar with C++, so I am not sure how to resolve the linker issue. I do know that this C++ code requires the file `LSL/liblsl/bin/liblsl64.dylib`. I assume that is the file that must be linked?

How can I wrap this C++ code in Go?

Here is the file structure:

```
LSL
├── liblsl
│   ├── bin
│   ├── distros
│   ├── examples
│   ├── external
│   ├── include
│   ├── project
│   ├── src
│   └── testing
└── liblsl-Generic
    ├── AUTOGENERATE\ HOWTO.txt
    ├── examples
    ├── liblsl.swigcxx
    ├── liblsl_c.i
    ├── liblsl_cpp.i
    ├── liblsl_wrap.cxx  # created by Swig
    └── liblsl.go        # created by Swig
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into this a few months ago, took longer to figure out than I would have liked, but I don't remember exactly what I did to fix it, but I think it was along these lines:

1. Don't call swig manually, it actually makes things a bit more difficult.  Clean out the files generate by swig.
2. Create a file a.go in libsl-Generic with the contents:

   ```
   package libsls-Generic
   ```
3. In theory you have some other file, say `app.go` that will use `libsls-Generic`.  Write `app.go` and `import libsls-Generic` appropriately.
4. Use `go build app.go`.  This should build the dependency as well.

I eventually figured out how to get `go` to incorporate the files manually generated by swig, but I forget the details now.  I do remember that when generating files manually with swig, I would have to manually delete certain files when rebuilding.  When running with just go, the build step was much simpler.

Comment: Thanks, this clears up how to use `go build` without `swig`. However, I get a similar error as I got when using `swig`: `linker command failed` (and many symbols were not found). The linker cannot find `LSL/liblsl/bin/liblsl.dylib`. I tried running `go build -ldflags "-L ../liblsl/bin -l lsl" app.go` but got the same linker error.

Comment: Have you tried specifying the dylib to link as a cgo comment?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16747021/how-do-you-statically-link-a-c-library-in-go-using-cgo

Answer (score -1):

1. Unzip liblsl release tarball and clone liblsl-Generic to a folder under Go home directory
2. Fix liblsl_cpp.i so that it points to the correct header file path
3. Run `swig -go -c++ -cgo -intgosize 32 -package liblsl liblsl_cpp.i`
4. Add `// #cgo LDFLAGS: -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib -llsl64` (assuming liblsl64.dylib is at `/usr/local/lib`) after `package liblsl` on the preceding line before the next comment in your liblsl.go
5. Run `go install`

That will make it, `liblsl.a` will be under Go home dir's `pkg` folder and you will be able to import it from Go programs.